# Are animated notification bar icons acceptable?

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, android-notifications, user-experience

I'm considering turning a static notification bar icon in my application to an animated one, since it seems that it would make identification of the app state a bit easier for users.

I've checked it and figured out that animated icons (`animation-list` `Drawable`s)indeed work in the notification bar.

But I can't recall I've ever seen animated icons in the notification bar except system ones (e.g. battery when charging). Also, I can't find guidelines from Google on this matter.

Are animated notification bar icons acceptable\recommended according to Google's requirements\guidelines?

Comment: you may try the GIF image, which every battery low charging application uses for their notification icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not recommended to use by Google but acceptable.

> Google: We make Android guidelines only to not follow them and force
>   everybody else to do the same.

I did not find any official Google guidelines for animeted Notification icons but there is a lot of usefull information

https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior

Comment: Thank you, I checked out multiple sources, including the Mterial Design article you've provided. But I'm looking for any specific reasoning for/against animated notification bar items from different points of view that might include UX, system resources consumption, compatibility across Android versions, etc.